# Свой шаблон для пагинатора

Tags: php, yii

Делаю в экшене так

```
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                    'totalItemCount' => $count,
                    'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>8,
                        //'pageVar'=>'page',
                        //'route'=>'/', 
                        ),
                    ));
```

передаю потом в шаблон, и вызываю виджет

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'row',
    'template'=> "{pager}\n{items}\n{pager}",

   'pager'=>array(      
        'maxButtonCount' => '10',
        'prevPageLabel'=>'&larr;',
        'nextPageLabel'=>'&rarr;',
        'header'=>'Навигация: ',
    ),
    'ajaxUpdate'=>false,

));
```

все бы хорошо, но ссылки генируются вида [site.ru/my/patch?page=2](http://site.ru/my/patch?page=2) , хочу изменить на ссылки такого типа [site.ru/my/patch/page_2.html](http://site.ru/my/patch/page_2.html) как это сделать ? И есть ли способы поменять саму html структуру пагинатора без заморочек ?

Comment: Ну так а где шаблон?

Comment: В смысле где шаблон ? Yii сам генеририрует шаблон для пагинатора, можно конечно лезть в ядро фреймворка но не думаю что это правильно.

Comment: Тогда скорее всего тебе в htaccess и там настрой чтобы URL был нормальный. и там сделать URL вида  site.ru/my/patch/page/2

или в настройках Yii

    'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',

Comment: С этим как раз проблем нет, проблема в том что виджет ссылки не правильные генерирует, вернее не того типа что мне нужно

Comment: стоп, а на кой смысл делеть так page_2.html чем тебя не устраивает ?page=2 эта запись-то?

я что-то проснулся недавно и не вкурил еще.

он добавляет гет параметр в url и все в норме.

Comment: Так поставлена задача просто)

Answer (score 2):

Дык может тогда иначе все сделать.

Есть какой-то контроллер.

Допустим, как у тебя **my**

```
 public function actionSome()
    {
        // выборка из таблицы
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $pagination = new CPagination(MODELKAKAYATO::model()->count($criteria));
        $pagination->pageSize = 5; // количество записей на странице
        $pagination->applyLimit($criteria);
        $result = MODELKAKAYATO::model()->findAll($criteria);
        // рендерим
        $this->render('blablabla', array(
            'res'=>$result ,
            'pagination'=>$pagination
        ));
```

Ну и рендер делаем такой (blablabla).

```
<?php foreach($result as $r) : ?>
<div><?php $r->title ?> - <?php $r->code ?></div>
<?php endforeach ?>
// ну а тут думай как лучше тебе сделать вывод своего пагинатора, но уи учитывай как контроллер будет его обрабатывать !!!
<? $this->widget('CLinkPager',array(
         'pages'=>$pagination,
)) ?>
```

Ну и выводи как тебе нужно.

Просто `Yii` свой пагинатор делает правильно по сути, переписывать его вывод не стоит ибо он ядро.

А вот сделать как бы "свой" пагинатор - это велосипед, но иногда приходится извращаться даже с такими фреймворками.

Думаю, помог :)

Comment: как раз хотел такого избежать) Там в настройках, если поигратся с PageVar, route можно изменить урл, но так как мне нужно у меня не вышло и нормального примера найти не удалось, только в анг документации пару строк. А с html структурой не критично, просто ради интереса спросил)

Comment: Ну может и можно избежать, но я пока не смогу рассказать как, ибо не сталкивался с такой задачей у себя в практике, ну а если эти грабли помогут то хорошо.

@tranceman, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Генерацию url думаю можно изменить с помощью роутеров.

2.А что мешает стилизовать кнопки как пример: http://media.vashmir.by/filter/year/59.html?page=7

Если желаете могу уделить время и помочь разобраться в всем этом.